# How to build nested menu "trees" in HAML

Tags: ruby, recursion, haml, tree

I am trying to build a simple nested html menu using HAML and am not sure how to go about inserting the elements with the [correct indentation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#find_and_preserve-instance_method), or the general best way to build nested trees.  I would like to be able to do something like this, but infinitely deep:

```
- categories.each_key do |category|
    %li.cat-item{:id => "category-#{category}"}
        %a{:href => "/category/#{category}", :title => "#{category.titleize}"}
            = category.titleize
```

It feels like I should be able to accomplish this pretty easily without resorting to writing the tags by hand in html, but I'm not the best with recursion.  Here is the code I've currently come up with:

**View Helper**

```
def menu_tag_builder(array, &block)
  return "" if array.nil?
  result = "<ul>\n"
  array.each do |node|
    result += "<li"
    attributes = {}
    if block_given?
      text = yield(attributes, node)
    else
      text = node["title"]
    end
    attributes.each { |k,v| result += " #{k.to_s}='#{v.to_s}'"}
    result += ">\n"
    result += text
    result += menu_tag_builder(node["children"], &block)
    result += "</li>\n"
  end
  result += "</ul>"
  result
end

def menu_tag(array, &block)
  haml_concat(menu_tag_builder(array, &block))
end
```

**View**

```
# index.haml, where config(:menu) converts the yaml below
# to an array of objects, where object[:children] is a nested array
- menu_tag(config(:menu)) do |attributes, node|
 - attributes[:class] = "one two"
 - node["title"]
```

**Sample YAML defining Menu**

```
menu:
  -
    title: "Home"
    path: "/home"
  -
    title: "About Us"
    path: "/about"
    children: 
      -
        title: "Our Story"
        path: "/about/our-story"
```

Any ideas how to do that so the output is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class='one two'>
    Home
  </li>
  <li class='one two'>
    About Us
  </li>
</ul>
```

...not like this:

```
<ul>
<li class='one two'>
Home</li>
<li class='one two'>
About Us</li>
</ul>
```

... and so it's properly indented globally.

Thanks for the help,
Lance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick to nicely-indented, Ruby-generated Haml code is the [`haml_tag` helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method). Here's how I'd convert your `menu_tag` method to using `haml_tag`:

```
def menu_tag(array, &block)
  return unless array
  haml_tag :ul do
    array.each do |node|
      attributes = {}
      if block_given?
        text = yield(attributes, node)
      else
        text = node["title"]
      end
      haml_tag :li, text, attributes
      menu_tag_builder(node["children"], &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something along the lines of:

```
def nested_list(list)
  return unless list
  haml_tag :ul do
    list.each do |item|
      haml_tag :li do
        haml_concat link_to item["title"], item["path"]
        if item["children"]
          nested_list item["children"]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is a beauteous use of haml_concat and I was able to get this technique to work in my app in about five minutes. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, @shingara's hint put me in the right direction :).  This works perfectly:

```
def menu_tag(array, &block)
  return "" if array.nil?
  haml_tag :ui do
    array.each do |node|
      attributes = {}
      if block_given?
        text = yield(attributes, node)
      else
        text = node[:title]
      end
      haml_tag :li, attributes do
        haml_concat text
        menu_tag_builder(node[:children], &block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If somebody can make that even shorter, or make it more easy to customize the attributes on the nested nodes, I'll mark that as correct instead of this.

Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

It's because you send a pur HTML by your helper. The indentation become with HAML. You can can generate some HAML in your helper.

Comment: It's not actually possible to generate Haml code in helpers and have it be rendered into HTML dynamically (unless you manually invoke the Haml compiler).